# Check expect example in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to Racket.

Can someone give me a simple example on how to use `check expect` in Racket, preferably with numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._test-engine%2Fracket-tests..rkt%29._check-expect%29%29) is your best friend.

It's really simple: the first parameter to `check-expect` is the expression or procedure to be tested, and the second one is the *expected* result (hence the name). Assuming that you've selected an adequate language (for example: `Beginning Student`)

```
(check-expect (+ 1 1) 2)
(check-expect (+ 1 1) 1)
```

The above will produce an output such as this:

```
Ran 2 tests.
1 of the 2 tests failed.

No signature violations.

Check failures:
    Actual value 2 differs from 1, the expected value.
at line 2, column 0
```